# Do I need BEGIN END in a MySQL trigger with one command?

Tags: mysql, triggers

In many trigger examples, BEGIN and END is used even when there is only one command.

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_employee_update 
    BEFORE UPDATE ON employees
    FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO employees_audit
    SET action = 'update',
     employeeNumber = OLD.employeeNumber,
        lastname = OLD.lastname,
        changedat = NOW(); 
END
```

Do I really need to use it? Otherwise, why should I use it?

Comment: What happens when you omit it? Probably that answers your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The body of a MySQL trigger technically can contain only one statement. More-complex trigger code uses `BEGIN ... END` to wrap multiple simple statements into a single *compound* statement suitable to this purpose. If your trigger body consists of a single *simple* statement this is not necessary and the `BEGIN ... END` can be omitted, although it does no harm to include it.